# Zigbee garage door button

Tags: garage-door-opener

I have that most basic of garage doors with that simple button (that looks like a doorbell) to open/close it.

I’m looking to replace that button with a zigbee one for remote control.

But I haven’t readily found one.  Is there a better name for that button.   Ive seen “relay switch” but idk if that’s the same thing

Any suggestions for a solution

Comment: You are talking about a wired-to-the-wall garage door button?

Comment: This SE is not supposed to be for product recommendations. However... I use a Gogogate device wired into my push button that provides for phone app control as well as reminders/notifications when the door is open, plus a temperature sensor.

Comment: Yes it's currently wired

Comment: Sorry for product recommendation thing.  I just haven't found one but it's so simple I figure it is out there just called something different

Comment: There are complete garage door remote control units, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/Solidremote-12V-Universal-2-Channel-Transmitters/dp/B01JGDV8UM/ref=sxin_9 - **not**   recommendation, just shown as example. *N.B.* Be sure the remote is reasonably secure, and wired so existing safety switches prevent forceful closing on a person or pet!

Comment: really looking for something with zigbee.  what is my garage door button?  is that considered a "low voltage switch"?  i see zigbee low voltage switches but not sure if thats what i need.